# dns_get_record using post from form

Tags: php, dns

I am trying to create a simple DNS query based on dns_get_record. I have scoured the internet for support on this but to no avail! Most likely because it is an old and outdated method. Nevertheless, I am having a hard time getting a form to work with the php. Any help would be appreciated.

index.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="dns.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="search"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

dns.php

```
<?php
$search = test_input($_POST["search"]);
$result = dns_get_record($search, DNS_ANY, $authns, $addtl);
echo "Result = ";
print_r($result);
echo "Auth NS = ";
print_r($authns);
echo "Additional = ";
print_r($addtl);
?>
```

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: I apologize, when i go hit submit and it opens dns.php its just a white screen. Nothing prints.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without `test_input` function?

```
$search = $_POST["search"];
```

Comment: OK, you can try the following: 0) Turn on PHP error logging, 1) `DNS_ALL` instead of `DNS_ANY`, 2) search on php.ini for the `disable_functions` setting, 3) update your PHP to version >= 5.3 **over a Linux box**.